# Getting two arduinos to interact without wiring them together

Tags: arduino

Okay, I've been working on this project for months with this being what has stopped me, heres the situation.

I am making a glove that can move a robot arm. The glove has an Arduino Nano iot 33 attached. The board measures the orientation with the built in imu, and sends it to my laptop (will be a raspberry pi in the future) through a usb cable. Also connected to the laptop is an Arduino Uno r3. This board is what makes the robot move (the servos are wired to it and I attached a display that shows the orientation of the glove here). I pondered how to make the Arduino Nano communicate to the Arduino Uno for a while, and I settled on keyboard presses. The Arduino Nano would press certain buttons based on its orientation and the Uno would wait for them to be pressed to move the robot. Turns out that after over 1000 lines of code, the Arduino uno can't use the keyboard library, and I'm stuck again. Is there a better way to go about this?? or is there a way to get the Arduino uno to get keyboard commands (I'm sixteen, tryin to save for college, I know theres a way to buy something to bypass the boards chip, I've already spent quite a bit on arduinos and PLA and such, and if im gonna buy something I want to use it again, please keep that in mind)

How would you have gone about this? How can I recover this project? Please help me...

Comment: why do you need the keyboard library in Uno? the library sends the keys it doesn't read them. the Uno has no way to read USB HID commands send by the keyboard library from Nano 33 IoT. you can use Serial communication. same as with Serial Monitor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is an amazing project.
Great idea the link over SerialUSB, but it is very very slow...
You should use a radio transmitter [like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076Q64MBQ).
Else, there is a great tutorial for communication using [Bluetooth](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=104903.0) master & slave (warning: the post is in Italian).

If you still want to use SerialUSB, you should use a program that reads input from Nano and send a hex. code into Arduino Uno.

Library for serial communication with [java](http://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/) or [ruby](https://github.com/hparra/ruby-serialport).
Library for serial communication with [Arduino](https://github.com/simonecocco/Arduino-USART).

I hope this can help you. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll be sure to check all of these out!